# Why is my ArrayList length 0 in my mouseClicked() function?

Tags: java, processing

In my processing program, I added an object into a global `ArrayList` called items in my draw function.

Here is the class.

```
class Obj {
    String name;
    Obj(String name) {
        self.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is my draw function.

```
void draw () {
    items.add(new Obj("Bob"));
}
```

I tried printing the size of items in my mouseClicked() function into the console, but I keep getting 0.

```
void mouseClicked () {
    print(items.size());
}
```

Why?

The ArrayList is declared at the top of my file after my class:

```
ArrayList<Obj> items = new ArrayList<Obj>();
```

Comment: Are you using winform on MS.net?

Comment: Add `items.add(new Obj("Bob"));` to the beginning of the `mouseClicked()` method. That way you can guarantee that you have something in `items`.

Comment: What do you mean "global ArrayList"? What class is it in? What class are each of those functions in? Is `draw` actually getting called?

Comment: By global ArrayList, I mean I declared item ArrayList at the top of my document (not within any function).

Comment: Either items in mouseClicked is not the same list as in draw(), or draw() is not getting called.  This is why SSCCEs are so often requested on these sites; you have left out the code that shows us exactly where items is declared, so we can't tell whether anything is wrong with its declaration.  And of course we can't tell you whether draw is called.  Put a trace statement on draw so you can be sure it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things which aren't quite there yet:

1. `self.name = name;` should be `this.name = name;`
2. You're creating tons of objects (based on framerate), but only checking the size of the array in `mouseCliked()` (also you might want to use `println()` instead).

Try this:

```
ArrayList<Obj> items = new ArrayList<Obj>();

void setup(){

}
void draw () {

}
void mouseClicked () {
  items.add(new Obj("Bob"));
  println("items size: " + items.size());
} 
class Obj {
    String name;
    Obj(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```